# Keeping track of ownership in a new relation using foriegn keys

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design, foreign-keys

I wanted to keep track of what users own what songs.
The user table:

```
+--------+----+
|username|name|
+--------+----+
|sam1    |Sam |
+--------+----+
|bil9    |Bil |
+--------+----+
|tomj    |Tom |
+--------+----+
```

The logic was to create a new relation to keep track of who owns what song...

```
+-------------+--------+
|user_username|track_id|
+-------------+--------+
|sam1         |1       |
+-------------+--------+
|bil9         |5       |
+-------------+--------+
|bil9         |9       |
+-------------+--------+
|tomj         |2       |
+-------------+--------+
```

Track id is a foreign key to the tracks table:

```
+--+------+
|id|name  |
+--+------+
|0 |track1|
+--+------+
|1 |track2|
+--+------+
```

Is this correct, or is there a more logical way of doing this?

Comment: If your intention is to model a many-to-many relationship, then yes - having a junction table is the correct way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

What you call "logic" is more of a lookup table.

Things to consider:

- 1 user can have multiple tracks? if so make sure track_id isn't unique.
- What you have done is good because if you change a track or user name the mapping stays the same.

One thing I would suggest is having a user id so that user_id maps to track_id - its always good to  have numbers map to numbers because its generally quicker to do queries, then you can change the text values as much as you like and they still map.

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense for the track_id to be unique based on how the tables are laid out? bil9 owns 9 and 5. Each of these ids can map to specific tracks. Also, the question implies that the id alone is the primary key to the tracks table.